Как получить изначальное значение в форме при использовании RadzenCustomValidator
Я использую компоненты Radzen.Blazor 4.31.6 в своем проекта ASP Net Core MVC (.NET 8).
Есть таблица RadzenDataGrid в которой можно добавлять новые строки и редактировать существующие. При добавлении новых строк происходит проверка с помощью RadzenCustomValidator чтобы пользователь не ввел уже существующий в базе данных артикул. Но, при редактировании параметров существующей строки уже невозможно сохранить/обновить её, так как этот артикул уже занят. Можно ли как-то при работе RadzenCustomValidator принимать предыдущее значение, которое изначально там было, чтобы исключить его из проверки? Да, это можно сделать уже на JS или JQuery, конечно...
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="RedBook" Property="ShifrRedBook" Title="Шифр">
    <EditTemplate Context="redbook">
        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="redbook.ShifrRedBook" Style="width:150; display: block" Name="ShifrRedBook" aria-label="Введите шифр" />
        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Необходимо ввести шифр" Component="ShifrRedBook" Popup="true"/>
        <RadzenCustomValidator Value=@redbook.ShifrRedBook Text="Этот шифр занят" Component="ShifrRedBook" Popup="true"
                               Validator="@(()=>!sservice.IsShifrExist(redbook.ShifrRedBook))"></RadzenCustomValidator>
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>

@code {
public bool IsShifrExist(string shifr)
{
  return _allShifres.Any(s => s.Equals(shifr));
}
}

Спасибо.
Посмотрел официальную документацию https://blazor.radzen.com/docs/api/Radzen.Blazor.RadzenCustomValidator.html - там нет примеров, какие параметры может принимать метод Validate
